Show there is a matching between students S in groups C1, . . . , Ck of size at most |Ci| ⩽ |S|/2 st. a student matches to a group they are not in
Here is the text of the question:
A set of students S have submitted their homework. The students have been collaborating on the
homework, forming $k$ disjoint collaboration groups $C_1,\dots, C_k$. The professor wants the students to grade
each other’s homework, but wants to avoid having a student grading the homework of a student from the
same collaboration group. Using Hall’s theorem, prove that this works (i.e., the professor can find a grader
for each student from another collaboration group) if each collaboration group has size at most $|C_i| ⩽ \frac{|S|}{2}$.
Here is what I am thinking: I draw a bipartite graph with students and collaboration groups, and draw an edge between them if a student is not in a particular collaboration group.
For a subset $A$ of students, for a given student $a \in A$  at most $\frac{|S|}{2}$ students are in the same group as them (including themselves). So the number of students in the same group as students in $A$ is $|A|\frac{|S|}{2}$. Then the neighborhood of $A$ is comprised of groups made up of only students $S-A$, of which there are $|S|-|A|\frac{|S|}{2}$ many such students.
How should I proceed from here? It's not clear to me how I should show Hall's condition (that $|N(A)| \ge |A| $).

Note that the number of students need not equal to the number of collaboration groups, so your bipartite graph need not have a perfect matching, leading to the conclusion that you are incorrect applying Hall's Marriage Theorem.

Consider a graph where each student is a vertex and its two vertices are endpoints of an edge if these students are not in the same group. Suppose it has no matching saturating all vertices of $C_{j}$, then its bipartite subgraph (whose vertices are endpoints of an edge if one of the student is in $C_{j}$ and the other student is in another group) also has no $C_{j}$-perfect matching and Hall's Theorem applies.
So, $ \exists A \subseteq C_{j}$ such that $|A| > |N(A)|$.
Because the bipartite graph is complete, $|N(A)|=|S|-|A|$.
Hence,
\begin{align}
|C_{j}| \ge |A| &\ge |N(A)| =|S|-|A| \ge  |S|-|C_{j}| \\
& \Rightarrow |C_{j}| > \frac{|S|}{2}
\end{align}

Thanks for the answer. So this is a proof by contradiction? And from where do we obtain a bipartite subgraph, is it not one already? I'm sorry for all the questions, I'm not good at following mathematical reasoning that seems obvious to most people.

@kybcr this is a proof by contradiction, the first graph is a $k$ partite graph because each group has vertices adjacent to all other vertices in all other groups.

(This is a hint and not meant to be a complete solution!)
I assume for this question that each student can only grade one piece of homework, otherwise this question will be trivially easy; pick one unlucky student from each group and have him grade the work of all other students in groups he is not part of.
Hint: for these kind of questions, work backwards. For the bipartite graph you've constructed, a perfect matching from collaboration groups to students corresponds to selecting $k$ students, such that for each $1 \leq i \leq k$, student $i$ is not in collaboration group $i$, which is not what you want.
Instead, try a bipartite graph $G = A \cup B$ with $A$ and $B$ being two copies of the students instead. How should you connect the edges such that a perfect matching corresponds to a permutation $\sigma: \{1 ,\dots, |S|\} \to \{1, \dots, |S|\}$ such that for each $1 \leq i \leq |S|$, student $i$ is not in the same group as student $\sigma(i)$?

(You might want to indicate that this is an incomplete solution to the problem, though it technically answers "How should I proceed from here?")
